# How to determine reasonable population density of a three-dimensional volume

Tags: space-constructs, population, logistics

I'm attempting to rough-estimate potential population density of three-dimensional megastructures in space. Assume a filled spherical volume (i.e. death star, not Dyson sphere), where all internal space is available. What would be a generally reasonable population-per-cubic-mile, assuming conventional transportation of resources (by which I mean no replicating food or teleporting out waste)? At what point would waste heat become a major concern for this structure in deep space? I'm currently just looking to land my estimate in the right order of magnitude, so perfect accuracy is less important.

Edit: It occurs to me that the estimate could also apply to large-scale arcologies on a planet, but I can't find that answer either, so consider that a potential alternate estimate method should you be more familiar with it.

Comment: *"At what point would waste heat become a major concern for this structure in deep space?"* Waste heat *is* a major problem from the very beginning. Look a photo of the International Space Station, and notice the large radiators. When [one of the radiators failed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station_maintenance#2010_%E2%80%93_Failure_in_cooling_loop_A) all other activity was dropped and the crew went to perform three emergency EVAs to repair it.

Comment: Look at existing high-density 3D "structures" like Manhattan and Hong Kong.

Comment: @AlexP: The ISS is far, far smaller than a small moon. Given the amount of care the Empire had for OH&S, they might simply consider a lack of insulation a good way to get rid of waste heat, even from the reactor core. It avoids unshielded vents.

Comment: @nzaman: You physics is backwards. The ratio between volume (where heat is produced) and area (where heat is dissipated) goes *up* when the radius increases. It is *harder* to get rid of waste heat on a large ship than on a small ship. And your idea about insulation is strange -- the ship is in a vacuum, and the vacuum is very good insulator by itself. That's why spacecraft (such as the ISS) need active radiators in order to dump waste heat.

Comment: Is your structure purely residential, or it has some industry and agriculture as well?

Comment: @Alexander Assume just residential. I can determine required food and resource import per person separately.

Comment: @RonJohn Those are still inherently 2d in nature, as we lack the material and engineering technology for mile-high, high-density buildings.

Comment: Knight, whether they're 5280 feet high, or 500 feet high, they're still 3D.  If you don't believe me, you need to learn what 3D means.

Comment: @RonJohn Let's put aside pedantry and I'll clarify, then. Every estimate related to population in those settings is still "per square kilometer". I don't have a good way to extrapolate that data into the form I'm looking for.

Comment: Knight, I'd look to see how many people live in a HK skyscraper (and, of course, see how big the skyscraper is).  Then... extrapolate.

Comment: @AlexP: But heat is _not_ produced uniformly throughout the volume, and as radius increases, volume increases cubically and for working areas, you have to afford a larger proportion of that volume for free movement, which further reduces the volume of heat sources. As regards the point of vacuum being an insulator, yes, but the hull isn't. Unless you insulate the interior, the ship will lose heat to the exterior from where it will radiate out into the vacuum. The radiators on the ISS are for _controlled_ heat loss, otherwise the inside would soon reach a few degrees above 0K, like the outside

Answer (score 5):

Let's run the calculations for heat dissipation as the only limiting factor. We assume that the sphere is a maximum density human habitat. All life support (oxygen, food, water) is coming from outside of this sphere. There is a practical limit, though, how quickly the heat could be pumped from out of this sphere that it stays cool.

Sphere volume: $V = \frac43\pi r^3$

Sphere surface: $S = 4\pi r^2$

$n$ - number of humans

$V_H$ - volume per human

$P_H$ - power per human (own metabolic plus lighting, devices and appliances)

$F$ - heat dissipation factor, watts per square meter of surface

*

With number of humans and other variables: $nV_H = \frac43\pi r^3$ and $nP_H = 4 \pi r^2 F$

$$nP_H = 4\pi\sqrt[\frac32]{\frac{3nV_H}{4\pi}}F$$

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{V_H^2}} = \frac{4\pi}{P_H}\sqrt[\frac32]{\frac 3{4\pi}}F$$

$$\frac n{V_H^2} = \frac{4 \times 3^2 \pi F^3}{P_H^3}$$

- this is the formula that ties up all the factors together. Let's try to get some practical numbers using it.

Let's assume $P_H = 200W$ and $F = 1000 \frac{W}{m^2}$

For 1,000,000 people: $V_H = 8.4 m^3$ (similar to first class sleeping railroad car) and $r = 126m$ (tiny, actually!)

For 1,000,000,000 people, $V_H = 266 m^3$ (more than double typical cruise ship's space) and $r = 3990m$

Practically, 1000 watt per square meter estimate is rather low. With advanced techniques we can transfer heat more efficiently. 200 watt per person means a very basic accommodations - lighting and small electronics, but no hot meals and no heating devices.

Overall, it appears like (without any energy intensive processes), heat dissipation is not going to be a major limiting factor for a space station size.

Comment: So it sounds like heat dissipation will only become a concern in the event of proximity to an outside heat source like a star (in which case it's a matter or surface area rather than scaling with volume), and relatively trivial to deal with in deep space?